# How can I use array filter to find value of value inside an object inside an array and then change/edit that value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Say I have something like this:

```
this.state = {
todos: [{id:0, text:this.state.text, isEdit: this.state.isEdit, priority: this.state.priority}, {id:1, text:this.state.text, isEdit: this.state.isEdit, priority: this.state.priority}, {id:2, text:this.state.text, isEdit: this.state.isEdit, priority: this.state.priority}]
};
```

And I have a var that is equal to 2 like this: `var = 2`

How can I ***use*** that var inside something like "Array filter()" (open to easier array method implementations for this scenario) inside a function, so that I can "extract" the ***entire*** object in the `todos:` array that contains the id's value in the example above, which is the ***same value as my var*** (`id:2`, in this example) and *then also*, modify/edit that specific object's `text:` value (this.state.text, in this example), while also ensuring that the object as a whole will be left in the same position as before? (This can be referenced by the id's/var's value, as it corresponds with how I am indexing).

In other words, how can I ***edit*** the text value of the object, that has a id that us the same value of my var?

I am told that this would be possible with the array filter method but I am having a hard time seeing how this is possible. Also I am a noob, so there's that... Would really value the learning opportunity though! Thank you in advance.

Comment: `.filter` is a bad idea, use `.find` instead, because you only want one object, not an array. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Ok good to know, and I have referenced https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find  for that, but I don't how I can target the number's value in a key/value pair. Like if there is an array of numbers, I can see how i can find that, but then what happens when the array is more complex as i am describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the function [`array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), use the function [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead to find an object according to a testing function which executes a condition.

> *The function [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns*
>
> The **value** of the **first element** in the array that satisfies the provided testing function; otherwise, [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is returned.

```js
let state = {  todos: [{    id: 0,    text: "text",    isEdit: true,    priority: 3  }, {    id: 1,    text: "text1",    isEdit: false,    priority: 3  }, {    id: 2,    text: "text2",    isEdit: true,    priority: 2  }]},
    id = 2,
    found = state.todos.find(o => o.id === id);

if (found) found.text = "NewText2";

console.log(state);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know it would return the whole object when you are specifying by the id. Thanks a lot @Ele!